# Cross browser alignment issues on wrapper

Tags: css, browser, compatibility, padding

[Here](http://archibaldbutler.com/projects/williamsmurrayhamm/) is the link to the website I am talking about.

My problem is that when you navigate between the different pages in the main navigation, the main wrapper does not align on the different pages I have used. So if you are on the home page and you click on "WMH" in the main navigation bar the whole page jumps to the left by about 8px.

This creates a jitter between pages that my client really doesn't like. I used some padding-left and padding-right in css to align it correctly. Unfortunately when I get it pixel perfect in Firefox, it is wrong in Chrome and Safari. If I get it pixel perfect in chrome, it jitters in Firefox. This is very irritating. I don't want to have to write separate styles for Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari unless it really is the only solution.

Thanks for your feedback. 
Archie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser scrollbar looks to be causing this. You can force a scrollbar to always appear which would solve the issue. Add this to your CSS:

```
html {overflow-y: scroll;}
```

You would also probably need to remove the padding that you tried to fix the problem with originally once the above style is in your CSS.

Comment: Thanks so much Wicky Wills, this was driving me up the wall, your solution worked perfectly. I have increased your stats, the least I can do. Cheers, Archie

Comment: Not a problem - glad to hear it :-)